# How can I show code while documenting an API using Flasgger

Tags: python, flasgger

I'm documenting an API and I'd like to show some code examples in order to show how does my api works, I'm using Flasgger and I didn't find any information about this topic, I read from x-codeSamples doc to show pieces of code by writing something like this but it's not working for me

```
  x-code-samples:
        lang: JavaScript
        source: console.log('Hello World');
```

so, how can I show pieces of code using flasgger?